# Traveling with the maiden name on visa

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, canada, paperwork, brazilian-citizens

My fiance and I, both Brazilians, want to visit my parents in Canada. She doesn't have a visa yet and we wanted to apply for one ASAP, to see if we can go there for Christmas. The problem is the visa is fairly expensive and we don't want to pay the process twice if we don't have to, but if we apply now, the name on her visa will be her maiden name, not the married name she will have once we marry.

If we get a tourist visa now, can she use a document such as a translation of her marriage certificate, carry two passports one with her maiden name and the other with the married name, or something alike to still hold a valid visa, or would the marriage render her visa useless?

Comment: Why not just travel with the old passport with the visa, and only apply for a new one with the new name after you have returned?

Comment: But would the visa still be valid, since she will have changed her name by the time we travel?

Comment: If the visa and passport are in the old name, her name *is* the old name as far as Canada is concerned.

Comment: Do people actually change name when they get married in Brazil, and is that automatic? In France for instance, even though in common usage they will use their husband's name (if they choose to!), legally ladies keep their maiden name, and the husbands's name will only be added to the maiden name written as "X EPOUSE Y" meaning "X wife of Y", X being the maiden name and Y the husband's name. But any passport or ID issued before marriage (without the mention) will continue to remain valid...

Comment: Yes, they do, it's actually a huge hassle because then the wife must change pretty much all her documentation and it leads to a whole bunch of problems, like this one.

Comment: Is changing one’s name after marriage *a legal requirement* or merely customary? How long before her current passport expires?

Comment: @JoãoAreias from what I can read this is incorrect. The wife **can** change her name if she so wishes, but she is absolutely not required to do so. Even if she changes her name, she can choose to just add her husband’s name (or more likely, one of them). However I haven’t found the exact procedure and timing for this. My guess is that as long as her current passport is valid, she has no need to renew it with her changed name (if she chooses to change it), but I can’t find the info.

Comment: It's not a legal requirement, but it's entrenched in our culture, we did talk as partners about that and she wants to change her name once we marry, the most common way of doing this and the way she wants to do is how I described, and the name is changed once the marriage papers are signed, typically on the marriage ceremony